# ServiceStack Funq RequestScope

Tags: servicestack, funq, servicestack-bsd

If I register a type with `RequestScope.Request`, and then I autowire it in a service, I know the object's lifetime scope will be respected.

Will this also hold true if I resolve the type in a non auto wired way, i.e.:

```cs
var authRepo = EndpointHost.TryResolve<IAuthenticationRepository>();
```

Also how can I confirm this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will the lifetime scope be respected when using `TryResolve` instead of autowire? Yes.

You can confirm this by setting up a project where you test the lifetime of a dependancy.
I created a test project to demonstrate this.

### [Full source code here.](https://gist.github.com/scottmcarthur/8775092)

I created 4 dependancies; 2 which are auto wired, consisting of a dependancy that will persist (static) across all requests, and the other which will only last for the request. The other 2 dependancies are created with the same respective `ReuseScope`s but they, are not autowired and will be resolved in using the `TryResolve` method. Thus:

```cs
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<AutoStatic, IAutoStatic>();
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<AutoRequest, IAutoRequest>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
container.Register<IResolveStatic>(c => new ResolveStatic());
container.Register<IResolveRequest>(c => new ResolveRequest()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

When each of the dependancies are created, their constructor method sets the time they where created on the `CreatedAt` property.

```cs
public class AutoStatic : IAutoStatic
{
    public string CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public AutoStatic() { CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.ToString(); }
}

    ...
```

The static dependancies i.e. `ReuseScope.Default` should always show the time of first request on all requests. The dependancies scoped as `ReuseScope.Request` should always have a new creation time on each request.

So our simple service that will prove this is:

```cs
public class TestController : Service
{
    public IAutoStatic AutoStatic { get; set; }
    public IAutoRequest AutoRequest { get; set; }
    IResolveStatic ResolveStatic { get; set; }
    IResolveRequest ResolveRequest { get; set; }

    public void Get(TestRequest request)
    {
        ResolveStatic = EndpointHost.TryResolve<IResolveStatic>();
        ResolveRequest = EndpointHost.TryResolve<IResolveRequest>();

        Console.WriteLine("-NEW REQUEST-");
        Console.WriteLine("Auto Static {0}", AutoStatic.CreatedAt);
        Console.WriteLine("Resolve Static {0}", ResolveStatic.CreatedAt);
        Console.WriteLine("Auto Request {0}", AutoRequest.CreatedAt);
        Console.WriteLine("Resolve Request {0}", ResolveRequest.CreatedAt);
    }
}
```

The results:

[image: Output]

So after 3 different requests, using both the autowire and the `TryResolve` method, we see that the static work as expected and the Request scoped likewise.

So use autowire or `TryResolve` the `ReuseScope` is respected.